# Entity Framework: Why SimpleMembership looking for Default Connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, simplemembership

I have explicitly set AccountsContext to use `mytestdb` as the connection string for SimpleMembership, as below -

```
public class AccountsContext : DbContext
{
    public AccountsContext()
        : base("mytestdb")
    {
    }
}
```

But Database initialized in following line of code is still looking for `DefaultConnection` for some reason. Although I have removed reference to `DefaultConnection` completely from web.config.

```
    public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
        private static object _initializerLock = new object();
        private static bool _isInitialized;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
            LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
        }
  }
```

[image]

Here is the Web.config file with commented sections -

```
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <!--<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />-->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mytestdb" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=mytestdb;User ID=****;Password=****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-LakshyaMvc-20130205074346;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-***.mdf" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
  </connectionStrings>

  <!--<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>-->
```

Any help in this regard will be much helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the `SimpleMembershipInitializer` private class inside the `~/Filters/InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs` file:

```
private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
{
    public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

        try
        {
            using (var context = new UsersContext())
            {
                if (!context.Database.Exists())
                {
                    // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                    ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                }
            }

            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Do you notice the following line:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

That's where it is coming from. By the way if you had looked at the exception stacktrace you got it would have pointed you to this location.

Also in the `~/Models/AccountModel.cs` file you might have the following context defined by default:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: super !, there it was. Thanks! However I couldn't find UsersContext, I could only see AccountsContext, whose connectionString I had already modified.